# Can I find the loss tangent of a substrate if I know the thickness of substrate and its relative permittivity?

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

What is the formula to calculate loss tangent for a substrate with relative permittivity 4.4 and height 1.58 mm? I need the value for designing a PIFA with 35-micron copper ground conductor.

Comment: Permittivity doesn't tell you about loss.

Comment: [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_loss).

Comment: Corsan and Lorrain discuss topics like this.

Answer (score 2):

No. Relative permittivity (a real number the way you specified it) and \$\tan\delta\$ are two different properties of a material. You can have a low-loss and a high-loss material with the exact same real part of the permittivity.

You should probably re-read your material; you'll find something about complex-valued wavenumbers, and you'll see why permittivity and loss are two orthogonal things.